# Which python 2.7 version I should use to run local instance of GAE?

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

The version of the stock python comes with OSX 10.9.5 is

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, Mar  9 2014, 22:15:05) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

The version of python coming from homebrew installation is

```
2.7.8 (default, Sep 22 2014, 11:59:25) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.51)]
```

Does it matter if the debug version number differ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm running Mac OSX 10.9.5 as well, and I have just been using the latest Python version that comes with OSX since App Engine 1.6.  You can view issues by specific app engine to Python version here:  https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/SdkReleaseNotes.  For example, "Fixed an issue where logging in the SDK was broken in Windows 7 using Python 2.7.2.".

I haven't had any issues with using the latest 2.7.* version of Python on OS X though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it matters. Why don't you just try installed the local gae server?

Comment: The local instance is running alright to me. But I do not know if there is any implication in future e.g. unexpected break after deployment to GAE servers. I did not find any reports of this being a bad thing, so I would appreciate input from the SO community.